Streaming voice response to twilio
I would like to stream audio to a Twilio phone caller. I have generated a URL and used ngrok to expose my localhost. Everything was working fine when tested in the browser.
At the moment, my experimental code looks like this:
@app.route("/speak", methods=["POST"])
def speak():
    return generate_voice_response("Hi! How can I be of help?")


def generate_voice_response(text):
    response = VoiceResponse()

    stream_url = url_for('stream_audio', text=text, _external=True)

    stream = Stream(url=stream_url)
    response.start().append(stream)

    print("Generated TwiML:", str(response))

    return Response(str(response), mimetype='text/xml')


@app.route("/stream_audio")
def stream_audio():
    text = request.args.get('text', "")
    print(text)

    audio_generator= ........

    return Response(audio_generator, mimetype="audio/wav")

As I mentioned, the generated URL from the logs works fine in the browser.
When I make a call to the phone, I can confirm that the "/speak" endpoint returns a 200 status code. I've verified this through the logs generated by the endpoint and the "generate_voice_response" function. However, it seems that the "/stream_audio" endpoint is not being accessed.
In the Twilio console, I notice there's an error code 11100, indicating an "Invalid URL" issue.
